# Soviet Luna 16 Spacecraft

Tags: soviet-union, luna

Is the Soviet spacecraft Luna 16 still working and transmitting temperature & radiation levels?  Attempts to Google the results of Luna 16 have failed, possibly because the results are in Russian.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No.  The Luna 16 descent stage used batteries and transmitted until the batteries ran out [1].

> Twenty-six hours after landing, explosive bolts were fired above the Luna 16
> descent stage. On a jet of flame, the upper stage shot off€ and headed towards the white
> and blue Earth hanging in the distance. It headed straight up, motor still purring,
> building up to lunar escape velocity, its radio pouring out details from the four aerials
> poking out the side. The Sea of Fertility returned to the quiet it had known for eons.
> The descent stage was the only forlorn reminder of the brief visit. The lower stage on
> the moon continued to transmit signals for a couple of days until the battery ran out.
> Only two instruments seem to have been carried: a thermometer and radiation
> counter.

[1] Soviet and Russian Lunar Exploration - Brian Harvey, page 243